# jQuery select2 with multiple select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Select2 2.1 and trying to apply it to multiple select tags with same id class.
My code looks like this:

```
<select id="e1" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
</select>
...
<select id="e1" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
</select>
```

The javascript code is use is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { $('#e1').select2(); });
</script>
```

The problem is that only the first select tag gets the proper select2 class.
I don't know if the select2 allows this type of usage (i could not identify this information in documentation), but another options would be the increment the javascript function `{ $('#e1').select2(); }` to permit `{ $('#e(1..999)').select2(); }`, after i will adjust php code `<select id="e<?php echo $i ?>" style="width: 300px">`, where $i is incremented.

How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Add a class to all the selects or select by HTML tag

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page even js document.querySelectorAll() doesn't care about it, jquery care

Comment: What is the issue you are facing..do you want to add a class to the select box..

Comment: As reported http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 ID must be unique per page, or your HTML is not valid; can't you use different classes instead?

Comment: If you want css class then it can be same but your ID should be unique...

Comment: i can make css id unique, but then i need to adjust the javascript code to increment `$('#e1').select2();` properly, any advice?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and mark it accept it to mark this question "solved". Do *not* edit the solution into your original question, that isn't how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do you really need to have 2 selects with the same id?

Secondly, to match both, you can do `$('[id="e1"]').select2();` - But you shouldn't imo.

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. But as you know, the answer is to not use multiple same Ids

Comment: I have the following code: `echo "<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('[id='e1']').select2(); });</script>";` which does not work.. what i'm missing?

Comment: In php you need to escape the quotes like this `echo "<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('[id=\"e1\"]').select2(); });</script>";` and this solved the case.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple elements with the same ID is VERY bad practice. Use a class instead...that's what they're for.

HTML:

```
<select class="select2" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
</select>
...
<select class="select2" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.select2').select2(); });
```